# How to alert a user when an event occurs?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create a news portal, on which if their is say a new event like "breaking news" 
and the user is viewing another website,he should be alerted by means of tab blinking or any sound or if the browser is minimized,it should open up by itself. Is it possible using php or jquery?

Comment: Playing a sound on your page, yes. Blinking a tab, no. Restore the window, hopefully not but some window managers *may* provide nasty JS-hooks. Another option: change the favicon of the page - this will be noticeable in the tab bar (in supporting browsers).

Comment: jensgram, can you provide any links. i have no idea how to do this..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dynamic+favicon should be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to open the browser by itself when it´s minimized, and even if it was your users would hate you! Firing a sound is annoying, instrusive, and the user does not have any way to know from which tab it comes from, so it´s not really useful either.

I think your most reasonable option is to update the page title when new items are available, as for example Gmail does when you receive new emails, which in my opinion works perfectly.

I guess you can also make the page / tab title blink changing it´s title with another timer function, but I dont think that makes much of a difference, and it would probably make your site look spammy.

So with your choice of technologies (PHP and jQuery), I think a good way to do this would be defining a JavaScript timer function that periodically checks for news (via AJAX, so you should also work in the backend for this, providing a data source for the latest news), and when a new one is published, fire another function that updates the page title with the unread news count.

The implementation of this isn´t very complicated if you are profficient with jQuery AJAX functions and Javascript in general.

If you need help, I can direct you to useful resources to do this, just tell me your specific doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into "server push" technologies. I recommend node.js and Socket.io to send an event from your server to the client/clients.